# Java Array Inside of Object

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I am trying to access an array that is part of an object.

I am getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at OrderedStringList.add(OrderedStringList.java:21) at Main.main(Main.java:24)"

I have cut my program down to the bare bones, cutting out everything that might be interfering with the output.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 5;

    OrderedStringList myList = new OrderedStringList();

    myList.add(x);
    }
} //end class
```

This code references the class OrderedStringList.

```
public class OrderedStringList {

public int values[];

OrderedStringList(){
    int values[] = new int[5];
}

public void add(int y) {
    values[0] = y;
    System.out.print(values[0]);
}
```

I assume that the numbers 21 and 24 in the error are line numbers. Because I have some things commented out in my original code, the code I have posted would normally have some content in the middle of it. Line 24 in main is: `myList.add(x);`. Line 21 of OrderedStringList is: `values[0] = y;`.

I'm guessing that there is something really simple that I am missing. Anything is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `Main.java:24` and `OrderedStringList.java:21` do indeed point to the class and line number you're having the error at.

Comment: In your constructor, `int values[] = new int[5];` declares a local variable `values`! Note, your compiler should have warned you about this unused variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here

```
OrderedStringList(){
    int values[] = new int[5];
}
```

You shadow the class member `values`.

Change this to:

```
OrderedStringList(){
    values = new int[5];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's been several months since I worked with java and I guess I was rustier than I thought. Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `values` twice....

```
public int values[];

OrderedStringList(){
    int values[] = new int[5];
}
```

This commonly known as shadowing.

Change the initialization of the array in the constructor to something like...

```
public int values[];

OrderedStringList(){
    value = new int[5];
}
```

Instead...

Answer (score 2):

This declares the `values[]` array just inside the scope of the method.

```
OrderedStringList(){
    int values[] = new int[5];
}
```

If want to refer to the `Class` scope use

```
OrderedStringList(){
    values = new int[5];
}
```

Comment: :-) Sorry, have just seen a lot of unbelievable "answers" tonight

Answer (score 1):

With the line `int values[] = new int[5];`, you're declaring an entirely new `int[]` that exists only in the constructor. Change it to `values = new int[5];`.